# How do i disqualify a parent document based on a key value pair in a child doc in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using parent child relationship in elasticsearch v7.3 suppose my parent document consist of 'users' also their are more than one child documents for each parent document. Now in all my child document i have with me a text field suppose 'name' with value 'raju' or 'yash' or etc. And my query is to get all the parent documents, whose child doc must not contain 'name' equals to 'raju'.

i.e if suppose we have 4 child doc in a parent doc and even if one child doc has name 'raju' then its parent doc must be disqualified and it must not be retrieved. hence i would request if anyone can help me with this.

```
                "has_child": {
                  "type": "child_1",
                  "query": [
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must_not": [
                          {
                            "match_phrase": {
                              "name": "raju"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inverse your query logic. The `must_not` clause should be on the parent side.

Could you test something like :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "has_child": {
                        "type": "child_1",
                        "query": {
                            "match_all": {}
                        },
                        "score_mode": "none"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "has_child": {
                        "type": "child_1",
                        "query": {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "name": "raju"
                            }
                        },
                        "score_mode": "none"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

NB : the filter clauses ensure returned document are parent document as pointed out in the comments

Comment: I Would request you to answer one more query of mine. link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57460431/11432290

Comment: facing some issue in your above posted solution as u said that i should use must_not on the parent level but i am noticing that keeping a must_not there also returns the child docs as it is working as a not condition overall.

Comment: i think this degrades the performance of query as all of the doc returned by must_not query are getting intersected with the parent doc returned by filter query, i have millions of documents so should i do this or their is a more efficient approach for it.

Comment: Did you experiment a performance drop or it is just an assumption?

Comment: I was actually experimenting with it from past few days and i did not notice this issue because this condition was always in intersection with a has_child query having must in it, but today i noticed it so that's why i asked you??

Comment: I added a score_mode option in the query, but I'm not certain that it will have a significant effect in performance.

Comment: I am using this query inside the function_score query so i have to give the score_mode.