# what are the points to be taken care of when using parent child relationship in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using es 7.3v and i have approx 5 TB of data that is to be indexed in ES in the form of parent-child relationship but I know that searching is 100 times slower using this relationship approach but my use case is such that i have to stick to it so i wanted to know what points should i take care of to improve the performance of my cluster also I have to run a lot of has_child and has_parent queries. 
Note: size of my parent doc is small but the size of child doc is large as it may consist of 100 fields in every child doc.

1. Such as the H/W requirements, i.e what should be suitable hardware on cloud that has to be used or any specific machines.
2. How to decide the number of shards.
3. How many nodes should be thier in the cluster to handle such amount of data.
4. Any more points that are important to be considered.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you "have to stick" to using parent/child relationship?

Comment: Because my data is such that i have a parent entity and a few child entities associated with it also i have to frequently insert and update parent, child docs in my cluster and so reindexing is efficient here moreover the overall relationship helps me to easily segment an entity based on other entity such as parents on the basis of child and vice versa.